# Get record from csv by column name

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv table (my csv file http://jpst.it/1GCd9)

```
| id | email | name | google.com | yahoo.com |
| 1  | email1@email.com | jack |   | + |
| 2  | email2@email.com | jack | + |   |
| 3  | email3@email.com | jack |   |   |
```

Is it possible to get emails that have "+" by column name?

For example I want to specify google.com and get email email2@email.com

I just know how to get data by column id :(

```
  while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }

      $explode = explode(";",$row[4]);
      echo $explode[4]. ", ";
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the actual input file, or perhaps the actual PHP script you are using (whichever is not current).

Comment: https://jpst.it/1GCd9

Comment: I would put it directly in the question here, it's kind of a hassle to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using sanitized CSV (removing all the excess white space and array filter you can get what you want.

I used `array_map('trim', array_filter(explode($delimeter, $lines[0]), function($entry){return !empty($entry);}));` to sanitize all input from whitespaces, and discard the "empty" header you have at the end by the last pipe character.

See the following functions: [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Then when everything is "normalized" we have an array of associative arrays with the correct fields, so we can search by using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) again. The variable `$only_with_plus` will then only contain associative arrays that match the search parameters.

```
$only_with_plus = array_filter($entries, function($entry) {
   return $entry['google.com'] == '+' && $entry['email'] = 'email2@email.com';    
});
```

See it online: https://ideone.com/ZDn2dv

```
<?php
$CSV = <<<EOF
| id | email | name | google.com | yahoo.com |
| 1  | email1@email.com | jack |   | + |
| 2  | email2@email.com | jack | + |   |
| 3  | email3@email.com | jack |   |   |
EOF;
$delimeter = '|';
$lines = explode("\n", $CSV);
$key_names = array_map('trim', array_filter(explode($delimeter, $lines[0]), function($entry){return !empty($entry);}));
$entries = [];
$len = count($lines);
for($c = 1; $c < $len; $c++) {
    $line = array_map('trim', array_filter(explode($delimeter, $lines[$c]), function($entry){return !empty($entry);}));
    $entry = [];
    foreach($line as $key => $value) {
        $entry[$key_names[$key]] = $value;

    }
    $entries[] = $entry;
}

$only_with_plus = array_filter($entries, function($entry) {
   return $entry['google.com'] == '+' && $entry['email'] = 'email2@email.com';  
});
var_dump($only_with_plus);

// your code goes here
```

Comment: One more problem, how about if I have columns with the same name? I get only one result https://ideone.com/0SjNNU

Comment: @user3514052 make sure you don't generate columns with the same name. Make whatever generates those column names assign them individual descriptive names. something like: gmail.com - google photos - google analytics. When your columns have the same name you're not giving values proper descriptions, they become meaningless. When all fails, rename them to google.com1, google.com2, but that's bad practice.

Comment: i cant do that, i got that csv file when export sendinblue campaign data.. :(

Comment: @user3514052 Then the question for you becomes, what does the second google.com mean? You'll need to build up your own translation of what it really means. So before you enter the for loop, walk the key_names array and replace the approriate entries with the correct names, **OR** define your own key names array instead of accepting the column names that were given to you. so, `$key_names = ['id', 'name', 'google_1', 'google_2'];` but do realize you'll need to know the format beforehand if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cant filter csv directly, but you can filter it after parsing it to array;

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f17969e35fcfc5e2f4b2f25202359f1b4cc4840b

Comment: the csv is set by string,because the sandbox cant work with files btw, you can set ih however you want

Comment: Tschallacka's answer is more detiled, just voted it up)

Comment: Can you answer what if i have columns with same name? I get only first result this way https://ideone.com/0SjNNU

Comment: the only solution i can see is to rename your columns in csv file or to rename it while you are converting it to array.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3afca448e31b73a6c07eeaefac96b51891649ae
But you should also remake the filtering method if you want to search by all duplicated colums simultaneously

Comment: I get an error because while reading only that count of rows, that count have columns http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/315c9379b1195f86df36102971095b75f2de2dfc

Comment: thank god you are, here. but your latest code give no result

Comment: are you sure csv is valid, it seem like the column count is not equall in header and some rows

Comment: yaeh I am sure, got same error with simplest csv http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b907f39bc0ef599d18b670d84516423ef45a747

Comment: you right, but there is absolutely good csv example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cbbfbfcec5c7d36d26ed283e0fe10158c01cafa

Comment: i've modified your code a bit and it seems to be working now http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97b551e7f938f50a40dfb83016473cc840d4ab13

Comment: спасибо тебе большое, похоже теперь действительно все супер! ты лучший))